# server side of Backbone urlRoot setup with Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, backbone.js, laravel

I am just starting to look at backbone.js but am struggling with the server side of things.

I have seen documentation declaring the urlRoot as `'user/'` after a bit of googling I have figured out that this is a reference to a RESTful API, however I have not been able to figure out how to implement such a structure with WAMP (will be moving to a hosted server once I have a working solution).

I had a play with `Laravel` but after 2 days I have not been able to set up a route to a dummy controller. This is my current attempt:

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('users', 'UsersController@create');
```

**UsersController.php**

```
<?php

class UsersController extends BaseController {
    public function index() {

    }
    public function create() {
        $input = Input::json();

        return json_encode($input);
    }
}
```

**backbone.js**

```
window.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        FirstName: "Test",
        LastName: "User"
    },
    urlRoot: "user/"
})
```

However when I create a new user and attempt to call save, chromes network tools tell me that it sends a post request to `users/` and then a get request to `users`

Is there an easier way to set my site up to talk with backbone or am I just doing something really wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

and

```
public function getCreate() {}
```

see this http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers